# Simplify this loop-built time dropdown?

Tags: jquery, loops, select

I"m creating a dropdown with options for each hour (0-23).

How would I simplify this js so the arr is a loop? As is is now, it's just as much typing as if I manually code each option in the html.

http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/zvj5pxqn/

```
$(arr).each(function() {
 $("#time").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, create a loop that increments the hours and create the time string on the fly:

```
var t = 11,
    a = "am";

for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++){
    if(i > 11){
        a = "pm";
    }
    if(t == 12){
        t = 1;
    }else{
        t += 1;
    }
    $("#time").append($("<option>").attr('value',i).text(t+":00 "+a));
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvj5pxqn/3/) for a working example.

As suggested by Pevara in the comments, you could speed up the process by adding the options to a variable and updating the DOM one time after the loop. As well as reduce the code with ternary  expressions inline like so:

```
var hour = 12,
    options = '';

for (var i = 0; i < 24;i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + i + '">' 
        + hour + ':00 ' + (i > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am') 
        + '</option>'
    ;
    hour = hour >= 12 ? 1 : hour + 1;
}
$("#time").html(options);
```

See their [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvj5pxqn/4/).

Comment: may I suggest to update the DOM only once, outside the loop. It will make a big difference to performance. I updated your fiddle (with some minor readability updates as well) http://jsfiddle.net/zvj5pxqn/4/

Comment: @Pevara, Absolutely. I didn't because I didn't feel it was part of OP's original question. Likewise, for some people ternary operations can be harder to read. I've updated my answer to include your code and fiddle though, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't rely on jQuery to do simple tasks. It's slower.
(Rephrased to friendly per comment by user, good advice, thanks Pevara)

This is faster. https://jsfiddle.net/fm43690a/
(originally stated 150x, but that was exaggerated. Even under different browsers JS performs differetly, some may take that seriously. In fact it is only 6-8x faster. See jsfiddle)

```js
var option, obj = document.getElementById("time");
for(x=0; x < 24; x++){
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = 
        (x===0) ? ("12:00 am")
 :(x<12) ? (x+":00 am")
        :(x===12) ? "12:00 pm"
        :((x-12)+":00 pm")
        ;
    option.value = x;                      
    obj.add(option);
}
```

```html
<select id="time"></select>
```

Comment: Be careful with bold statements like that, if you would have measured it you would have seen that your code is actually slightly slower, definitely not 150x faster. If jQuery is already on the page, there is no harm in using it, if you use it wisely that is. If you really are going for performance, you should only update the DOM once, outside the loop, since that is clearly where the bottleneck is. See for yourself: http://jsperf.com/manipulate-dom-in-loop

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short one:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 23; i++) {
    var clock = (i < 12) ? 'am' : 'pm';
    var hour = (i > 12) ? i - 12 : i;
    $("#time").append($("<option>").attr('value', i).text(hour + ':00 ' + clock));
};
$("#time option:first").before($("<option>").attr('value', 0).text('12:00 am'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="time"></select>
```